# How do I register "custom" Op (actually, from syntaxnet) with tensorflow serving?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to serve a model exported from syntaxnet but the parser_ops are not available. The library file with the ops is found (out-of-tree) at:

`../models/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/bin/syntaxnet/parser_ops.so`

I'm currently hacking the mnist_inference example, (because I don't know how to build anything out-of-tree with bazel), and the command I'm running is:

`./bazel-out/local-opt/bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_inference --port=9000 /tmp/model/00000001`

And the error I'm getting is:

`F tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_inference.cc:208] Check failed: ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (bundle_factory->CreateSessionBundle(bundle_path, &bundle)) (OK vs. Not found: Op type not registered 'FeatureSize')`

And FeatureSize is definitely defined in the parser_ops.so, I just don't know how to load it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with TF (I work on Bazel) but it looks like you need to add parser_ops as a dependency of mnist_inference.

There is a right way to do this and a wrong (easier) way.

## The Right Way

Basically you add syntaxnet as a dependency of the example you're building.  Unfortunately, the syntax net project and the tensorflow serving project import tensorflow itself under different names, so you have to do some mangling of the serving WORKSPACE file to get this working.

Add the following to the tensorflow_serving WORKSPACE file:

```
local_repository(
    name = "syntaxnet",
    path = "/path/to/your/checkout/of/models/syntaxnet",
)
```

This allows you to refer to the targets in syntaxnet from the tensorflow project (by prefixing them with "@syntaxnet").  Unfortunately, as mentioned above, you also have to get all of syntaxnet's external dependencies into the WORKSPACE file, which is annoying.  You can test out if it's working with `bazel build @syntaxnet//syntaxnet:parser_ops_cc`.

Once you've done that, then add the cc_library `@syntaxnet//syntaxnet:parser_ops_cc` (parser_ops.so is a cc_binary, which can't be used as a dependency) to [mnist_inference's deps](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/BUILD#L59):

```
deps = [
    "@syntaxnet//syntaxnet:parser_ops_cc",
    "@grpc//:grpc++",
    ...
```

Note that this still won't quite work: `parser_ops_cc` is a private target in syntaxnet (so it can't be depended on from outside its package) but you could add an attribute to it like `visibility = ["//visibility:public"]` if you're just trying things out:

```
cc_library(
    name = "parser_ops_cc",
    srcs = ["ops/parser_ops.cc"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
    ...
```

## The Wrong Way

You have a .so, which you can add a src file for your binary.  Add the directory it's in as a `new_local_repository()` and add it to `srcs` in the BUILD file.

WORKSPACE file:

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "hacky_syntaxnet",
    path = "/path/to/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/bin/syntaxnet",
    build_file_content = """
exports_files(glob(["*"])) # Make all of the files available.
""",
)
```

BUILD file:

```
srcs = [
    "mnist_inference.cc",
    "@hacky_syntaxnet//:parser_ops.so"
],
```

Comment: I've done all of this and I now get `ERROR: Loading failed; build aborted.` - that's the only error message. I've verified there are no typos. In fact, I added a few just to check what could be causing it and it gets as far as the "...parser_ops_cc" part of deps before it's failing.

Comment: I can't see a situation where this message by itself (with no other messages) isn't a bug, so I've opened an issue with bazel itself: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1401

Comment: Commented on the bug and updated the answer with a hack that should work around this.

Comment: Please note to readers: "The Right Way" works, but in my particular situation, there are currently incompatibilities between the three projects (Tensorflow, Tensorflow Serving, and syntaxnet) pertaining to the handling of protobufs, and other naming issues in general which are still T.B.D.  I got this particular problem fixed thanks to this answer but now syntaxnet doesn't build... (I'm workin on it!)

Comment: One more note, (just because I got burned by it badly), in the target that is added as a dependency, in this case "parser_ops_cc" from the syntaxnet/BUILD file, you MUST have alwayslink = 1 in ALL of it's dependencies, or the Op will be present but fail to register an OpKernel. It was missing from one of the ops in syntaxnet and caused strange errors.